# Connect to Azure IoT Hub using MQTT

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I am trying to connect to an Azure IoT Hub directly using MQTT using this method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device

I am using MQTT explorer for windows: https://mqtt-explorer.com/
I enter the following details. My ioTHub is called IoTHub and my device is called device, so as per the documentation:

Protocol: mqtt://
Host: iothub.azure-devices.net/?api-version=2018-06-3430
Port: 8883
Validate Cert: Off
Encryption: Off
Username: iothub.azure-devices.net/device/?api-version=2018-06-30
Password: SharedAccessSignature sr=iothub.azure-devices.net&sig=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXredactedXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&se=1642603375&skn=iothubowner

No ports are blocked from my location. The connection fails and says disconnected from server.
If I try with TLS encryption it says not authorised.

How can I access the IoTHub using MQTT?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track! One small detail is missing, in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device)

Quote:

> For the ClientId field, use the deviceId.

The client ID can be set using the advanced settings, as seen in the two screenshots below:

[image: advanced settings]
[image: client ID field]

As for TLS Encryption, it's required. Switch it on and you should be able to connect.

Edit:
As you mentioned in the comment, the connection string was also wrong. You need the Shared Access Signature for a device. An easy way of generating one is by using the `az cli`. When you run the command below, you provide the connection string of your device (you can get it from the portal) and it will create the Shared Access Signature for you.

`az iot hub generate-sas-token --connection-string "HostName=iot-Hub.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=deviceId;SharedAccessKey=foo"`

Comment: Ok, I have entered the deviceId but I still get unauthorised. Could it be the SAS that was generated was for the IoTHubOwner?

Comment: Good catch, I've updated my answer with a way to get the SAS for a device.

Comment: @johnstaveley, I do recommend to read the document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support?WT.mc_id=IoT-MVP-5004034#using-the-mqtt-protocol-directly-as-a-device. Also, you can use a tool *Azure IoT Explorer* for generating a device sasToken.

Comment: @johnstaveley, this is not my action

Comment: ok, sorry #bewildered

Comment: I will add to @MatthijsvanderVeer excellent answer, that when you generate your SAS token, you may want to specify a duration longer than the default of 1 hour, so use the flag: --duration <seconds>