# MQTT: Connection to Azure IoT Hub (Micropython)

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, micropython

I'm unable to connect to Azure IoT Hub using the umqtt.simple2 library with SSL using MicroPython v1.22.2.

```
from umqtt.simple2 import MQTTClient

HUB_HOSTNAME = "AzureIoTHubHostName"
PORT = 8883
CLIENT_ID = "DeviceId"
USERNAME = f"{HUB_HOSTNAME}/{CLIENT_ID}/?api-version=2021-04-12"
PASSWORD = "SASToken"
TOPIC = f"devices/{CLIENT_ID}/messages/events/"
MESSAGE = b"Hello Azure IoT Hub!"
CADATA_PATH = "cadata_path"

with open(CADATA_PATH, "rb") as f:
    cadata = f.read()

ssl_params = {"cert_reqs": ussl.CERT_NONE, "cadata": cadata}

client = MQTTClient(
    CLIENT_ID,
    HUB_HOSTNAME,
    port=PORT,
    user=USERNAME,
    password=PASSWORD,
    ssl=True,
    ssl_params=ssl_params,
)

client.connect()

client.publish(TOPIC, MESSAGE)

client.disconnect()
```

No error message is provided by the connect method, making it difficult to diagnose the issue further (it fails on line 267 in simple2, when wrapping the socket --> self.sock = ussl.wrap_socket(self.sock_raw, **self.ssl_params))

I have tested my certificate file with openssl to check if the handshake occurs (openssl s_client -connect), and it works ok.

Could anyone advise on how to resolve this connectivity issue with Azure IoT Hub using MicroPython? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Connection to Azure IoT Hub  with [Micropython](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things-blog/micro-python-on-esp32-to-send-telemetry-to-azure-iot-hub-with/ba-p/1236022)

Answer (score 0):

The code below is used to connect a device to Azure IoT Hub using MQTT with Python. It sets up a connection to Azure IoT Hub using the `umqtt.simple2` library and publishes some telemetry [data](https://pypi.org/project/micropython-umqtt.simple2/).

- I followed IoTMQTTSample [python](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/IoTMQTTSample/blob/master/python/main.py)
- MicroPython on ESP32 sends telemetry to Azure IoT Hub with [MQTT](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/internet-of-things-blog/micro-python-on-esp32-to-send-telemetry-to-azure-iot-hub-with/ba-p/1236022).

```py
IOT_HUB_NAME = "{iothub_name}"
IOT_HUB_DEVICE_ID = "{device_id}"
IOT_HUB_SAS_TOKEN = "{sas_token}"

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("connect: " + str(rc))

def on_publish(client, userdata, mid):
    print("publish: " + str(mid))

# Create an MQTT client instance
mqtt_client = MQTTClient(client_id=IOT_HUB_DEVICE_ID, server=IOT_HUB_NAME + ".azure-devices.net", port=8883)

# Set the connection callback
mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect

# Set the publish callback
mqtt_client.on_publish = on_publish

# Set username and password
mqtt_client.username_pw_set(username=IOT_HUB_NAME + ".azure-devices.net/" + IOT_HUB_DEVICE_ID + "/?api-version=2021-04-12", 
                            password=IOT_HUB_SAS_TOKEN)
```

```py
messages = ["Accio", "Aguamenti", "Alarte Ascendare", "Expecto Patronum", "Homenum Revelio"]
for i in range(len(messages)):
    print("sending message[" + str(i) + "]: " + messages[i])
    mqtt_client.publish("devices/" + IOT_HUB_DEVICE_ID + "/messages/events/", payload=messages[i], qos=1)
```

- Connect to Azure IoT Hub using [MQTT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70788177/connect-to-azure-iot-hub-using-mqtt)

```bash
az iot hub generate-sas-token --connection-string  "HostName=<your-hub-name>.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=<your-device-id>;SharedAccessKey=<your-shared-access-key>"
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Hi Sampath, thanks for your answer! Your implementation does not quite work but it is a step forward. I needed to adjust to use the umqtt.robust2 library. The username and password need to be passed directly to the MTQQ Client as parameters. But the messages don't get to the Azure IoT Hub. When i check the connection using the mqtt_client.is_conn_issue() method, there is a connection issue detected.

Comment: follow the reference for umqtt.robust2 [library](https://pypi.org/project/micropython-umqtt.robust2/)and for the connection issue make sure to troubleshoot .